# NSTimer freezes when calling with UIViewAnimation

Tags: iphone, ios6, nstimer, uiviewanimation

In my project I am calling `NSTimer` 1000 times in a second. and with it I am allocating 5 `UIImage` objects per tap in some image view at same time with `UIViewanimation`. when I am doing that work the `NSTimer` freezes  for some seconds or delaying. I know why it is happing because I am making more then 100-120 `UIImageView` objects in a seconds.The timer is dong fine when I am not calling UIAnimation. i Used `[performSelectorInBackground:withObject:]`  to perform `UIViewAnimation` in the background.but in it the UIAnimation is not working .

Both `NSTimer` and `UIViewAnimation` is working on UI.so they are working on main thread. I can not make a different thread for them . what can I do to stop freezing of the `NSTimer` and calling `UIViewAnimation` in same time.These is because of the heavy computing. and I can not make sepererate thread for that what can I Do to workthat.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That can be happening because of PNG images you are using for animation inside UIImageView.

Why not try using JPEG representation

```
UIImage *newImage=[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.5)];
```

then use newImage as it will have less size than png one.

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
             //UIViewAnimation code
         });

Comment: same result buddy any more suggestion.